# SharpSvn for Git

Tags: c#, git, svn, libgit2sharp

I am currently using SharpSvn to do logs, commits and other activities, programmatically in C#.

As we are shifting to Git from Svn, I am looking for a best alternate for SharpSvn for Git.

I attempted to use SharpGit, but it does not seem to have friendly APIs. I am getting error 401.

The other one - LibGit2Sharp is still Pre-Release.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!
            GitClient gitClient = new GitClient();

```
        GitFetchArgs gitFetch = new GitFetchArgs();
        gitFetch.All = true;
        GitInitArgs gitInit = new GitInitArgs();
        gitClient.Init(@"C:\Work\TestGit");
        gitClient.Authentication.Credentials += new EventHandler<GitCredentialEventArgs>(Authentication_Credentials);
        GitClientArgs gitClientArgs;
        bool bFetch = gitClient.Fetch(@"C:\Work\TestGit", gitFetch);
```

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp 0.21 is already a production release. Hope you spend some time learning how to understand the version numbering rules.

Comment: There is also [NGit](https://github.com/mono/ngit), but having used both libgit2sharp is better, and also more actively worked on.

Comment: Thanks @adrianbanks for sharing your suggestion and experience. Seems LibGit2Sharp works fine as per my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with LibGit2Sharp; it works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I have started with LibGit2Sharp. Looking at the 'down votes' trends on this question, I felt this forum is too rude, as if I asked what is binary operator.

Comment: @RevathiDuraiswamy Yeah, someone downvoted this answer as well. Feel free to mark it as the accepted answer if you want :)

Comment: Thanks @David Deutcsch. I had to search through 'how to accept the answer' as I failed to notice the grey-colored right mark just below down vote button.